# Multiple txt files to a 2D array C#

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

So I want to add 7 txt files and each one is written like;

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

And

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

Each txt file will basically be a column in the 2D array. I know how to make a singular txt file into a 2D array but would like a way to have each column of the 2D array as separate txt files.

Before asked, this is the way I have to do it. As a challenge set by superiors.

This 2D array uses both string, integer and float data types.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As for your "superiors", this sounds MUCH like a homework assignment. Nothing like getting the internet to do your homework. :)

That being said, here's what I would do:

Create a new object that has one property for each of the files that you want to load in:

```
public class MyHomeworkClass
{
    public int a { get; set; }
    public string b { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Next, create a loop for each line in each file. For the first file, you have to create a new object. for all subsequent files (assuming they all have the same number of rows), you just re-use the existing objects.

```
    public List<MyHomeworkClass> LoadFiles(...)
    {
        List<MyHomeworkClass> ret = new List<MyHomeworkClass>();

        List<string> fileA = File.ReadAllLines("your starting file");

        // For the first file, just create a new object for each line
        foreach (string a in FileA)
        {
            MyHomeworkClass newMHC = new MyHomeworkClass();

            // Convert to an integer for your object
            newMHC.a = int.parse(a);

            ret.add(newMHC);
        }

        // Now, for each remaining file, use the number of "A" entries
        // to drive which object(s) you update.
        List<string> fileB = File.ReadAllLines("your file B");

        for (int x=0; x < ret.count; x++)
        {
            MyHomeworkClass mhc = ret[x];
            string line = fileB[x];
            // No need to convert this since it is already a string.
            mhc.b = line; 
        }

        // repeat the steps for fileB for each subsequent file.


        // Once all files are loaded, return your object.
        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you help but in the first line of the second section is something supposed to go in the brackets after LoadFiles?

Comment: ... is general pseudo-code for "Put whatever you need here"

Comment: Hi, I am having more issues with this. I added it in exactly how you've typed it into my application and it is coming up with a mountain of errors